# Unable to change font size with @media

Tags: css, media-queries, font-size

I am trying to have a menu that reduces in font size as the browser window gets smaller.  Here's what I've got:

Css:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 1115px) {
    /*Make font on menu smaller*/
    nav a {
        font-size: smaller;
    }
}
    nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
        transition: 0.5s ease;
        white-space: nowrap;
        height: 20px;
        color: #171581;
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-size: medium;
    }
```

HTML

```
<nav>
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="top-menu" id="about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="top-menu" id="residential">Residential &amp; Business</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="top-menu" id="myaccountdetails">My Accounts Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="top-menu faqs active" id="faq">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="top-menu" id="contactus">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

As far as I can tell from what I've read on the forum this *should* be working but when I resize the window there is no effect.

This question is not an exact duplicate.  This post is asking what was wrong, the other post is asking why it is this way.

Comment: Did you try putting the @media block after the original style block?

Comment: What is the font size of its parent element?  Is it set?  That might be affecting you.  Check out: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-size/

Comment: Apparently you do.  Thank you for that.

Comment: In response to your edit, the duplicate post answers both *what was wrong* and *why it is this way*. Your question is an exact duplicate. But if you disagree, you can post a comment below and vote to reopen.

Comment: No need to reopen.  The question is answered now.  Just following the instructions on the page that said to edit my question and explain why it wasn't a duplicate if I felt it wasn't, so I did.  And while the other question may come to the same conclusion, the reason I don't think it's a duplicate is that the title is asking something that I wouldn't (didn't) find when looking.  Asking why something is a way doesn't help someone who's trying to determine what's wrong with something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`font-size: medium;` is always applied as it appears after the media query. Simply re-order your styles:

```
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 20px;
    color: #171581;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: medium;
}

@media screen and (max-width : 1115px) {
    /*This is later in the order of styles, so will be applied when the screen is <= 1115px */
    nav a {
        font-size: smaller;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xo3cq44t/